# Usb4java error communicating with Device

Tags: java, usb, device, libusb

Need your help here.

I'm currently developing Java application that can communicate with a ingenico iWL220 device, using usb4java from libusb Library. I installed the driver and it can be read from Device Manager just fine. I mainly follows the code at

http://www.mets-blog.com/java-usb-communication-usb4java/ for the Low API.

http://www.mets-blog.com/java-usb-communication-usb4java-high-api/ for the High API.

The first one i tried is the Low API, my Main Class is as follows:

```
public class DeviceHandles {
private static final Short VendorID = 0x079b;
private static final Short ProductID = 0x0028;    
public static void main(String[] args){
UsbLowPos upos = new UsbLowPos();
upos.claimDevice(VendorID,ProductID);
   }
}
```

And this one returns with an error:

```
Device Found 
Exception in thread "main" org.usb4java.LibUsbException: USB error 12: Unable to open USB device: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform     at Usb.UsbLowPos.getDeviceHandle(UsbLowPos.java:121)    at Usb.UsbLowPos.findDevice(UsbLowPos.java:103)     at Usb.UsbLowPos.claimDevice(UsbLowPos.java:27)     at Usb.DeviceHandles.main(DeviceHandles.java:24)
```

After that, i tried the High API and my Main Class is this:

```
public class DeviceHandles {
private static final Short VendorID = 0x079b;
private static final Short ProductID = 0x0028;
public static void main(String[] args){
UsbHighPos upos = new UsbHighPos();
UsbDevice usbDevice = upos.findDevice(VendorID,ProductID);
upos.readMessage(upos.getDeviceInterface(usbDevice, 0), 0);  
   }
}
```

And this also returns with an error of:

```
javax.usb.UsbException: Properties file javax.usb.properties not found.     at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.setupProperties(Unknown Source)     at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getProperties(Unknown Source)   at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.createUsbServices(Unknown Source)   at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getUsbServices(Unknown Source)  at Usb.UsbHighPos.getUsbRootHoob(UsbHighPos.java:29)    at Usb.UsbHighPos.findDevice(UsbHighPos.java:43)    at Usb.DeviceHandles.main(DeviceHandles.java:27) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at Usb.UsbHighPos.findDevice(UsbHighPos.java:49)    at Usb.UsbHighPos.findDevice(UsbHighPos.java:43)    at Usb.DeviceHandles.main(DeviceHandles.java:27)
```

Am i missing something here? Is it the Library that can't communicate with the device? or maybe the problem is with the device? Please help, thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved, i used Java Serial Connection instead for it, and it works just fine!